# New to Python - need installation assistance

Tags: python, installation, ide, spyder

I want to install an IDE to use Python.  I have previously used Pycharm, Spyder.

I cannot use Spyder because I get kernel errors - no matter the answers on stackoverflow or the net, it doesn't work for me (i.e., update anaconda, update jupyter, etc.)

I cannot use Pycharm because it doesn't recognize a module I've installed via the command prompt.  When I install pip install inscriptis, i get this message:Requirement already satisfied

Yet inscriptis doesn't appear in the package list.

Can anyone help solve my above problems, or can someone recommend a solution that will work a little better.  It's frustrating spending so much time on install.  I had been very satisfied with Spyder, but I can't get the kernel to load.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Unfortunately this question is not for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that when using Pycharm each project has its own python interpreter.
You can look at the currently defined interpreter and the installed modules in that interpreter under
File->Settings->Project->Project interpreter
There you can also use the + sign to install modules specifically for the used interpreter.

To use the primary installed python (the one you downloaded and installed) and not a copy, in the project interpreter window, on the top right there is a gear icon. Click on it and choose add. Then, choose the lower option - an existing interpreter - and insert the installed python64.exe (assuming you run windows 64 bit).

Then, when you install using cmd (for pip - "python - m pip install ") it will appear in your project

Comment: Thank you this solved it.  I really appreciate the feedback.